# Delete and element of a vector and leave the empty space as it it in c++

Tags: c++

I have a vector:

```
x = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7;
```

I want to delete an element of that vector and leave the empty position as it is:

[image: the new vector]

How to do this in C++?. I am quite confused with the keyword I should use to find the correct question for this problem.

Comment: `std::vector` can't have empty spots. What if we removed the element at `x[2]`. I don't understand what result you would expect for `x[2]` afterwards.

Comment: you can have `std::vector<std::optional<int>>` but I doubt that would be a viable solution

Comment: @Slave: Looks perfect to me

Comment: Although depending on the requirements (which haven't been given) a sparse collection may be more appropriate, i.e. `std::map<int, int>`, with gaps detected at some later time when needed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes Master!

Comment: @Slava: Very good, slave!

Comment: Yes std::optional is exactly meant to add N/A to types that don't have such state in type.

Comment: You create a vector of integers. When you remove one integer, you actually mean that you want to scrub its information. But the vector is something stored in memory, so when you call the element again, it will translate its designated sequence of bits into an integer. There is no such thing as an integer variable with no value assigned to it. I would suggest to, instead of removing it, assign a distinguishable non-naturally-appearing value to it. Example, if they are all positive integers, just replace them with -1.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  What high-level problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: use a sentinel value to indicate empty - -1, 0, MAX_INT,.... depends on your use case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "empty" `int`, so a contiguous sequence of `int`s, such as a `std::vector<int>` cannot have "empty" elements.

You could use `std::optional<int>` which does have the concept of "no value"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <optional>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & os, const std::vector<std::optional<T>> & vec)
{
    for (auto & el : vec)
    {
        if (el)
            os << *el << ' ';
        else
            os << "  ";
    }
    return os << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::optional<int>> vals = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    std::cout << vals;

    *std::find(vals.begin(), vals.end(), 5) = std::nullopt;
    *std::find(vals.begin(), vals.end(), 6) = std::nullopt;

    std::cout << vals;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect this is actually overkill for whats probably an XY problem that really has a simple solution

Comment: Yes, half the lines here are for showing the values in the vector, but I stand by the first sentence. And `std::optional<int>` is a much better avenue to go down than `std::unique_ptr<int>` or `int *`.

Comment: std::optional is new to me, looks v useful - its like System.Nullable in c# I guess (C# has built in syntactical sugar for it tho - `int?`)

Comment: @pm100 no, `std::optional<T>` is like `Maybe<T>` in C#, `Nullable<T>` is `std::unique_ptr<T>` or `std::shared_ptr<T>` or `gsl::observer<T>`

Answer (score -1):

The real problem is that I need to rearrange voxels (representing a 3D image) after removing some parts of the voxels (like cropping a small volume from that initial volume). I have tried using "break" in the loop. However, the empty spaces are always filled by the next values. So I think what I can do is probably assigning the empty values with other numbers or completely let the empty spaces as it is.

Well...I maybe overthinking the problem as what some people said. But I do really need solution for this problem. Anyway, thank you for helping me :).

Comment: It sound's like you don't actually need the gaps. You can *remove* elements from anywhere in a `std::vector` (although it is most efficient to remove the last element)

Comment: I want to remove some voxels from the entire volume and maintain the position of the remaining voxels. In sort, I want to create a hole within the initial volume.

Comment: "the position" sounds like you don't actually want a sequential container, but instead an associative container. Instead of `std::vector<std::vector<Voxel>>`, you would have `std::map<Position, Voxel>` or similar